# What axioms satisfy a limit ordinal?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Let us consider the pair $(\alpha,\in)$ where $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal. The question is what axioms of ZFC satisfies that pair. I think it satistifies all axioms but I'm not sure...

Comment: I suspect not. If $\gamma,\delta\in\alpha$ is there a $\beta\in\alpha$ with $\beta=\{\gamma,\delta\}$? Pairing and Comprehension.

Comment: Ohh thanks!! But, why not comprehension?

Comment: It could be that "your" definition of Pairing is: $\forall a\forall b\exists z\left[\forall x\left[x=a\vee x=b\right]\Rightarrow x\in z\right]$.
In that case you still need Comprehension to achieve a set $\left\{ a,b\right\} $.
That's why I mentioned it. Pairing can also be defined as $\forall a\forall b\exists z\left[\forall x\left[x=a\vee x=b\right]\iff x\in z\right]$.
Then mentioning Comprehension is irrelevant.